# GCM push notification return error: field data must be a json array

Tags: php, json, wordpress, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When I am using GCM for push notification , I got an error return as: field "data" must be a JSON array. 
When user create the new post then notification will be send to all Registered devices. Any one have some idea of how to solve it? Thank you.

```
function Notification($post) {
    global $wpdb;
    $pub_post = get_post($post_ID);
    $post_title=$pub_post->post_title;
    $totalrecord = $this->get_allrecord(); 

     $message = "Your New post, " .$post_title." has been published";
      if (count($totalrecord) > 0) {
        //$display_row = null;
        foreach ($totalrecord as $row) {
        $a = $row->token;
        $this->sendPushNotification($a, $message);

            }
        } 
     } 

function get_allrecord(){
  global $wpdb;
  $results =$wpdb->get_results('SELECT token FROM wp_push_tokens ', OBJECT);
  return $results;
  }

 function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {
    $apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
     $headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:" . "key=" .   $apiKey);
     $fields = array(
        'register' =>$registration_ids,
        'data' =>$message  );

     $ch = curl_init();
// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
// Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, wp_json_encode($fields));
// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
   if($result === false)
        die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());
// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your content type is `"application/json"`, which means the `"data"` field must be a JSON of the form :

```
"data": {
    "message": "your message"
}
```

Note that the `"message"` key in this example is custom. You can use whatever keys you wish, and your app will have to search for those keys when it receives the message.

I don't know PHP, but something like this may work :

```
 $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' =>$registration_ids,
    'data' => array('message' => $message));
```